# HAXM not working on AMD processor

Tags: android-studio

i am running an AMD processor and when i try to install Intel HAXM it says you have to have an intel processor. So does this mean I cannot run  AVD on my machine? please help

Answer (score 0):

It only means you can't run Intel HAXM. You can still use the basic slow emulation or a tool like genymotion.